# Import a dictionary into the current scope as variables

Tags: numpy, python, scipy

I have a .mat file in which I put data previously processed. When I perform

```
dict = scipy.io.loadmat('training_data.mat')
```

I get back a dict that is like this

```
{'encoders' : ......, 'decoders' : ........, 'stuff' : .....}
```

I want to selectively import the **encoders** and **decoders** variables into my current scope. The effect is the same as:

```
encoders = dict['encoders']
decoders = dict['decoders']
```

How do I cleanly do this without typing 10-15 lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could import a dictionary `d` into the global scope using

```
globals().update(d)
```

The same thing is impossible for local scopes, since modifying the dictionary returned by `locals()` results in undefined behaviour.

A slightly hacky trick you could use in this situation is to import the names into the dictionary of an on-the-fly created type:

```
d = {"encoders": 1, "decoders": 2}
t = type("", (), d)
print t.encoders
print t.decoders
```

This will at least be slightly more convenient than using `d["decoders"]` etc.

Alternatively, you could use `exec` statements to create your variables:

```
d = {"encoders": 1, "decoders": 2}
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    exec k + " = v"
```

This could also be done selectively.

Comment: I believe you actually want locals() not globals() as he specified the current scope. locals().update(d)

Comment: @John: As already pointed out in my answer, modifying the dictionary returned by `locals()` is not supported -- just look it up in the docs.